# Baloo not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, baloo

The new KDE indexing service is of fundamental importance (as was Nepomuk before it) but, unfortunately, it does not work as it should on my machine with Kubuntu 14.04.
Indeed, it does not work at all, both via Dolphin nor via the Milou interface.

I already [filled a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333652), but I wanted to know if someone has experienced the same problem and maybe solved it, or has some idea on where to look for a solution or more informations on what is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the same issue, in "Ubuntu" 14.04.  In 13.10 Dolphin "Find" work flawlessly, however since upgrading to "Trusty" "Find" returns no results at all.

It appears this is a problem which may not be resolved until KDE 4.14.  Note the latter part from the following extract:

"....A major new improvement is the introduction of KDE’s next generation Semantic Search. This makes search faster, saves memory, improves stability, and generates more reliable search results. And it could use a good testing.

Various applications use the search abilities, most notably Dolphin and KDE PIM (see the next section). Also tagging (Gwenview!) and KRunner (Alt-F2 run command dialog) can use some attention.

Some of your existing data will need to be migrated from the current Nepomuk backend to the new 'Baloo' backend. Running the nepomukbaloomigrator should take care of that. The old Nepomuk support is considered “legacy” (but it is still provided). The programs that have not yet been ported to the new architecture have Nepomuk integration disabled. One significant regression is file-activity linking, which will not work until KDE Applications and Platform 4.14. If you rely on this feature, we recommend not upgrading at this time. For the final release, distributions might choose to optionally have the old search (Nepomuk) available.  ...."

..."

Above extract taken from:  http://dot.kde.org/2014/03/12/applications-413-coming-soon-help-us-test

Comment: Why should we waiting for 4.14?

Comment: Moreover, can you please confirm that the bug affects you also, on its webpage that I linked before? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had multiple installs of Kubuntu on multiple devices, and file search never worked. However, today I found a workaround!

Open System Settings and go to Search -> File Search. Disable the checkbox 'Enable File Search'. Searching for files should now work, at least in Dolphin.

Thanks to [PangentFlowers on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/96ac26/can_dolphin_search_for_files_or_not/e4ce89h/).